# Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: timeout: Read timed out

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to integrate my maven project with SonarQube but when I try to run

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -X
```

I'm getting this error

```
[DEBUG] 13:09:55.647 Create: /Users/gab/.sonar/cache/_tmp
[DEBUG] 13:09:55.650 Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
[DEBUG] 13:09:55.657 Get bootstrap index...
[DEBUG] 13:09:55.658 Download: http://localhost:9000/batch/index
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  08:23 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-04T13:18:15+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project api-server: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: timeout: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project api-server: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0 (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart (EmbeddedScanner.java:181)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start (EmbeddedScanner.java:122)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex (BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles (JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download (JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0 (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart (EmbeddedScanner.java:181)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start (EmbeddedScanner.java:122)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException (Okio.java:232)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit (AsyncTimeout.java:285)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read (AsyncTimeout.java:241)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.read (RealBufferedSource.java:47)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.read (Http1Codec.java:363)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1Codec$UnknownLengthSource.read (Http1Codec.java:507)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.request (RealBufferedSource.java:68)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals (RealBufferedSource.java:418)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals (RealBufferedSource.java:402)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset (Util.java:469)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.ResponseBody.string (ResponseBody.java:175)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString (ServerConnection.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex (BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles (JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download (JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0 (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart (EmbeddedScanner.java:181)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start (EmbeddedScanner.java:122)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0 (Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead (SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$2.read (Okio.java:140)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read (AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.read (RealBufferedSource.java:47)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.read (Http1Codec.java:363)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1Codec$UnknownLengthSource.read (Http1Codec.java:507)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.request (RealBufferedSource.java:68)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals (RealBufferedSource.java:418)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals (RealBufferedSource.java:402)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset (Util.java:469)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.ResponseBody.string (ResponseBody.java:175)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString (ServerConnection.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex (BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles (JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download (JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0 (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart (EmbeddedScanner.java:181)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start (EmbeddedScanner.java:122)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I was able to access it on my browser (htttp://localhost:9000). I can also download the boostrap index using wget on my Terminal. I'm running Sonar via Docker using this command.

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube
```

I also tried to download the Sonar package from the site itself and run it via Terminal but I'm encountering the same problem. I have tried both Sonar 7.9.1 and 7.7 as well as other versions of SonarScanner plugin (3.2, 3.6.0.1398, 3.7.0.1746) but to no luck, the problem still persist.

**pom.xml** here are the things I added related to sonar

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
</plugin>

<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have Zscaler installed on My mac and shutting it down resolved my problems. Seems like it is blocking the traffic.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the default port from 9000 to something else should also help. It is then not necessary to shut down ZScaler.

Comment: changing from default port 9000 to 9095 worked for me with Zscaler up.